# Combine offsetLimitPagination with filtering Apollo Graphql

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm implementing a pretty advanced table (using React-Table) for a large, complex set of data. I started by following Apollo's guide implementing offset-based pagination, I got sorting to work as well. What I'm stuck at is combining that with server-side filtering.

My definition of `InMemoryCache` looks like this - I'm querying a field `Targets`:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          Targets: {
            ...offsetLimitPagination(),       
            read(existing, { args }): any {
              if (args && args.limit !== undefined && args.offset !== undefined) {
                return existing && existing.slice(args.offset, args.offset + args.limit);
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

which is pretty much the outcome for what the guide told me to do for Pagination. My component queries backend:

```
const { networkStatus, error, data, fetchMore, refetch } = useQuery<GetTargetsQuery, GetTargetsQueryVariables>(GET_TARGETS, {
    ...
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    variables: {
      limit: tableState.pageSize,
      offset: tableState.pageNumber * tableState.pageSize,
      orderBy: tableState.orderBy,
      where: {
        _and: [initialFilters, queryFilters],
      },
    },
  });
```

The issue is, when I'm modifying the `queryFilters` and data gets refetched, I'm seeing correct data in my Network Tab in browser, but my component still reads the old data from the cache. It seems like the `offsetLimitPagination` hook is not exactly crafted for incorporating filtering(?).

I can't use the React-Table's built-in filtering, as it only operates on the data that has been queried (which in my case is part of the entire set). **How do I modify my `InMemoryCache` to overwrite the data in cache if there are new filters set?** Or is there a better way to tackle this or better question to ask to get this done?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/key-args/

Comment: I'm unclear what to specify there, if the only thing that really changes there is the content of my "where"

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the `keyArgs`, you'd want to specify the keys that would connect one cache from another.

In your case, you have the variables `limit`, `offset`, `orderBy` & `where`.

So in the case of changing the limit & offset, you do not want Apollo to create a separate cache when limit & offset changes. So you leave that out of the `keyArgs`.

The keyArgs that you want to watch is your changes with `orderBy` & `where`. From my understanding, the new `keyArgs` are what you want to base your cache from. So if anything in the orderBy & where changes, you'd want Apollo to treat it as somewhat of a separate dataset.

Also, `offsetLimitPagination` accepts a keyArgs prop.
So in terms of nested variables like the variable `where`, you can configure it in the keyArgs as a nested value so Apollo has an idea of what the inside of those values are.

The nested array syntax applies to the previous argument value (where).

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          Targets: {
            ...offsetLimitPagination(["orderBy", "where", ["_and"]]),
            read(existing, { args }): any {
              if (args && args.limit !== undefined && args.offset !== undefined) {
                return existing && existing.slice(args.offset, args.offset + args.limit);
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```